# Buttons not working properly on Wordpress Mobile

Tags: wordpress, button

working on wordpress I just realized that some buttons are not working properly on the Mobile Web, but only when I use a phone, if I test the mobile version on my pc, works perfectly fine. I tried different solution, but I can't find a reason what is going on, I deleted the cache but still not working.

Do you have any suggestion, of what could I do?

Comment: Hello friend, if your site is online, please send the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you test on your PC, are you sure the screen is exactly the same size as the phone you are testing with?  Usually, if a button doesn't work on a smaller screen it's because an invisible element is overlapping it.

On your PC, I'd try inspecting elements around the button to see if there is something (like a div element) that might be sliding in to cover the button at certain screen sizes.  You might also test on your PC using all the mobile screen size options it has, especially the smallest one, to see if you can get the problem there.

To more fully rule out this possibility, assuming you aren't in a production environment (in which case you could create a test page to try this on), you might add some CSS styles to button to make its position fixed, its z-index 99999999, and top, left, botton, right = 0.  This way, the button should fill the screen and you should be able to click anywhere on the screen to test it.

Comment: Thanks Chad for your answer, yes I tried on my PC and as well on my Phone, on the PC works everything smoothly, but on the phone, now I realized was a problem with one of the plug ins, that were installed, somehow the "delay js" for optimization made one of the error. Now I am able to navigate and click everywhere I want. But because programming is not perfect, another problem arises, now I have a pop up problem, and the cache is not being stored on the phone, so everytime I go to each page I am being asked if I am >18 yo.

Comment: Good that the first problem is solved.  If a plugin is creating the popup, and it's not working properly on mobile as you describe, I would try another plugin.